# Convert all columns to float if certain column are digits python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to convert all my columns to float **if** the certain column are digits.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
for columns in range(len(df.columns)):
  for rows in range(len(df)):
    if str(df.iloc[rows,columns]).replace('.','',1).isdigit() == True:
      df.iloc[rows,columns] = float(df.iloc[rows,columns])
```

It works well, but it takes a long time to run because of the data frame size. Does anyone have any idea for a simpler, much efficient code?

Comment: hi! can you post an example (in code!) of an input dataset and expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply `pandas.to_numeric` to all the columns. By specifying `errors='coerce'` the non-numeric values will be converted to NaNs.
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html

Then pass the DataFrame to `fillna` to fill the NaNs with the original non-numeric values.

This should be faster than the other answer for large DataFrames.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([["x", 1, "2.1"], [3.2, "y", "5."]], columns=list("ABC"))
>>> df

     A  B    C
0    x  1  2.1
1  3.2  y   5.

>>> df = (
       df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce', downcast='float')
         .fillna(df)
)

>>> df

     A  B    C
0    x  1  2.1
1  3.2  y    5

# confirm that the values are floats
>>> type(df.at[0,'C'])
float
>>> type(df.at[1,'C'])
float
```

Answer (score 3):

Does this answer your question?

```
df =  df.apply(lambda i: i.apply(lambda x: float(x) if str(x).replace('.','',1).isdigit() else x))
```

Comment: it works! just wondering how does using lambda function results in a faster execution compared to loops?